# Set zoom level to see only 3 pins in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and I'm using the Google Maps nuget for iOS and Android. I have a ListView with different places that I click to navigate to the MapPage to see the location of the place there.

Since the pins on the map are on different places I cannot set one zoom level for every location. I always want the 3 closest pins to be shown upon entering the page.

I have tried these solutions but I'm looking for a Forms solution for this problem.

```
 LatLng marker1LatLng = new LatLng(marker1lat, marker1lng);
 Latlng marker2LatLng = new LatLng(marker2lat, marker2lng);

 LatLngBounds.Builder b = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                                    .Include(marker1LatLng)
                                    .Include(marker2LatLng);
```

Also tried this but no luck:

```
var markers = [];//some array
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
 bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

How to dynamically set the zoom level depending on the lat & lon of those 3 pins that I want to be visible.

I have a total of 10 pins for each place on the map but only wanna show closest 3. Once I zoom out i wanna be able to see all 10 tho.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to find the three closest pins to the selected location, which I assume you will want to be the center of the map. Once you find the three closest pins, calculate how far the furthest of the 3 pins is and the use the

```
map.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (
            new Position (centerLatitude,centerLongitude), Distance.FromKilometers (distanceToThirdPin)));
```

where `centerLatitude` and `centerLongitude` are the coordinates of the selected location that will be at the center, and  `distanceToThirdPin` is the calculated distance (in Km) to the farthest of the 3 pins.

Formula to calculate distance between a pair of latitudes and longitudes:

```
double R = 6371.0; // Earth's radius
var dLat = (Math.PI / 180) * (pinLatitude - centerLatitude);
var dLon = (Math.PI / 180) * (pinLongitude - centerLongitude);
var lat1 = (Math.PI / 180) * centerLatitude;
var lat2 = (Math.PI / 180) * pinLatitude;

var a = Math.Sin(dLat/2) * Math.Sin(dLat/2) + Math.Sin(dLon/2) * Math.Sin(dLon/2) * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2);
var c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1-a));
var d = R * c; // distance in Km.
```

So use the above formula to find the distances to all of your pins, then find the three closest. Once found, use the distance to the third closest pin as the `distanceToThirdPin` value when you call the `map.MoveToRegion` method.

Comment: Im stuck on the first part. I have one activitypin and 5 other pins (11 total) that I want to be visible initially. I fetch lat, lon and distance from HTTPClient. However, I only get the distance between activitypin and other pins. @jgoldberger - MSFT

Comment: Huh? 1 + 5 != 11 </confusion>  but that does not matter. If you have the lat/long for all of the pins, you can calculate the distance from each of your 11 pins to the center location's lat/long, then get the distance of the furthest pin you want to include, and use that distance and the center lat/long as arguments to the `map.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (
            new Position (centerLatitude,centerLongitude), Distance.FromKilometers (distanceToThirdPin)))` method call