# AnimateCamera in GoogleMaps is not displaying all location included in builder

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin

I am working with GoogleMap and I am trying to focus my map on a region that displayed my list of locations. The list gets "included" into the builder one by one, but when I actually call this method a lot of my locations are cropped out. Seems to me like the zoom level on the NewLatLngBounds is too high.
I thought about getting the Northeast and Southwest Corners and then centering the map but that doesn't work either. Not sure what else to try.

```
public void DisplayRegion(List<Position> positions, int padding = 0)
{
   if (_googleMap == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Map is not ready");
  LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new    LatLngBounds.Builder();
   foreach(var p in positions)
   {
     builder.Include(new LatLng(p.Latitude, p.Longitude);
   }
     LatLngBounds bounds = builder.Build();

     //var ne = bounds.Northeast;
     // var se = bounds.Southwest;
   _googleMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(bounds, padding));
}
```

This does work but like I said above a good chunk of the locations passed in are cropped off screen. I also tried factoring in the width and height of the and basing padding on that but it's like I didn't do anything. All I want is for every item in my List of Positions to display on screen at an appropriate zoom level. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. First , select a location as the center of the map,just get the midpoint from  `Northeast` and `Southwest` Corners , let's say we get a point ,it has `centerLatitude` and `centerLongitude`  .
2. Calculate how far are the positions between the center location , and get the `farthest` distance , call it `farthestDistance`.
3. Use `map.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (new Position (centerLatitude,centerLongitude), Distance.FromKilometers (farthestDistance)));`

Then the map will display including all the positions and use a proper zoom level .

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53735393/8187800 .

Comment: May I ask have you solved the problem? If you have any other question please let me know.